# Fresco Android GIF/WEBP animation not playing

Tags: android, fresco

I decided to use `Fresco` as it offers solution to my problem: `GIF` and `WEBP` playback.

According to the documentation: http://frescolib.org/docs/animations.html

I can use these codes to automatically play animation:

```
   Uri uri;
   DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
       .setUri(uri)
       .setAutoPlayAnimations(true)
       . // other setters
       .build();
   mSimpleDraweeView.setController(controller);
```

However, when I used the code, it only displays the static image.

Are there any other steps I need to do in order to play the GIF/WEBP? or am I misunderstanding the documentation's use of 'animation'?

EDIT:

Additional info, upon using a ControllerListener, I found out that the Animatable return in onFinalImageSet() is null. I'm not sure why.

I also tried running this sample project but also the .gif doesn't animate: https://github.com/kaedea/fresco-sample-usage

I'm using a Nexus 5X for testing btw (version 6.0.1)

Comment: ok the issue is I didn't add the modules for GIF and WebP support

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that you add the [Gradle dependencies for animations](http://frescolib.org/docs/index.html):

```
dependencies {
  // If your app supports Android versions before Ice Cream Sandwich (API level 14)
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:1.2.0'

  // For animated GIF support
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.2.0'

  // For WebP support, including animated WebP
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.2.0'
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.2.0'

  // For WebP support, without animations
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.2.0'
}
```